# Как создать объект в JS один раз и навсегда?

Tags: javascript, веб-программирование, ооп

Как создать объект в JS один раз и навсегда? То есть при клике мыши мне надо что бы создавался объект и вызывался метод, далее если я еще раз кликаю, мне надо что бы использовался этот же объект.

Comment: Создать его вне события "клика" ?

Answer (score 5):

Вам нужно создать объект вне функции обработки события клика. В функции обработки проверять был ли объект уже создан. Если нет, то создавать его.

```
let obj;

function onclick(){
 if(obj === undefined){
  obj = новый объект;
 }

 используем obj
}
```